# htaccess - htpasswd: different AuthUserFile depending on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, .htpasswd

It's been a couple of days looking at how I could manage to have different AuthUserFile paths depending on my subdomain.

**Why do I have this problem:**
The admin access of my site is protected by htaccess - htpasswd. I'm now managing the repo with bitbucket and am configuring the automatic deployments. Because of this deployment system, I need to use the same files for every site instance: let's say I have:

```
local.mysite.com
staging.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
```

The problem is now that the AuthUserFile absolute path is different for each "site", so I would need to define it based on the subdomains.

**What I attempted to do:**
I was thinking about using If statement like that:

```
<If "Host == 'local.mysite.com'">
AuthUserFile
</If>
```

But I'm running apache 2.2 so not available.

I then thought about using something that would look like:

```
SetEnvIf HOST ^local\.mysite\.com$ ENV_LOCAL
<IfDefine ENV_LOCAL>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password required"
    AuthUserFile /my/local/path/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

But apparently, the IfDefine cannot read the SetEnvIf variables.

And now I'm blocked and can't find anything to help me on internet.
I'd be better if I didn't have to change the apache configuration too..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, seems to be pretty much impossible so I will just create a script that will generate the .htaccess files automatically on deploy and put the .htaccess in the .gitignore so I won't have conflicts when trying to pull.